# Threejs sprites are getting displayed with the wrong aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I am not sure what is causing this, but I am trying to render two objects in an Orthographic camera, and they are not rendering correctly, and I am not sure why.

The two images are supposed to look like this:

[image: Objects Normal Images]

But when rendered within threejs, they look like this:

[image: Squished Images]

As you can see the paddle is squished. The chunk of code is where I setup the canvas, renderer, etc to display on the page. This is how I setup the canvas:

```js
import { animationFrames, tap } from 'rxjs';

export class Game {
  static renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true
  });

  // Starts the renderer
  static start() {
    this.updateRendererSize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateRendererSize.bind(this));
    document.querySelector('.container')?.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    /* Snipped: Load all objects into the scene. */

    animationFrames().pipe(
      tap(() => this.renderGame())
    ).subscribe();
  }

  // Sets the renderer size
  private static updateRendererSize() {
    const aspect = this.game.aspect; // 1.777
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth / aspect);
  }

  // Renders the scene/camera
  private static renderGame() {
    this.renderer.render(this.activeScene.scene, this.activeCamera.camera);
  }
}
```

This is how I am creating the camera.

```js
export class GameCamera {

  camera: Camera;

  private aspectRatio = 1.7777777777777777;
  private size = 5;

  private readonly width = options.size;
  private readonly height = this.size / this.aspectRatio;

  constructor() {
    const dim = this.cameraDimensions();
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(
      dim.left, dim.right,
      dim.top, dim.bottom, 
      0, 100);
  }

  private cameraDimensions() {
    const left = this.width / -2;
    const right = this.width / 2;
    const top = this.height / 2;
    const bottom = this.height / -2;
    return { left, right, top, bottom };
  }
}
```

This is how I am loading the textures:

```js
  loadResource() {
    const map = new TextureLoader().load(this.resource);
    this.material = new SpriteMaterial({
      map,
      precision: 'highp',
    });
    this.object = new Sprite(material);

    /* Snipped: add sprite to scene. */
  }
```

Comment: To me it looks like they are on 1x1 grid, you should look for something like sprite size and pass there size similar to aspect ratio of images

Comment: Pretty sure you need to pass additional args in “new Sprite(material)”

Comment: sprite.scale.set( x, y, 1 );  where x y is aspect ratio of texture

Comment: That kind of works, the problem is that setting the size is in world units but the image is in pixels. Any idea what to do there?

Comment: Well you there is two solutions, the regular aspect ratio formula is height=1 width= (1/height) * width

Comment: The second one would be to for width=1 then height=(1/width)*height

Comment: If you want to answer the question, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi so Sprite in 3d engine is usually a textured plane that is 1x1 unit in world space.

Since your texture aren’t square you have to set size for sprite explicitly, to do so in threejs you have to use:

```
sprite.scale.set( x, y, 1 );
```

where x and y would be aspect ratio of texture

to calculate aspect you have two general options:

1. against height (default)

```
const height = 1;
const width =(1/texture.height)*texture.width;
```

2. against width

```
const width = 1;
const height = (1/texture.width)*texture.height;
```

There are options also to use min max to fitIn or fitOut of the 1 by 1 square

and if you want to tweak size you can replace 1 by factor so you can scale sprite according to your scene and camera setup

Comment: It seems as if when using this, the scale then affects items that get added as children, so the paddle is correct but if a ball gets added as a child, the scale of that child element is changed an the ball gets stretched. Any idea what that is causing that affect?

Comment: Yes, in three js a child component would inherit parent transform and set.scale would change transform. Idk sprite used if you need a lot of them with instancing, if you want just one image you can use plane or grid with texture, that will let you  change the mesh size without affecting transform

Comment: You have a one more option that is called Group, you can combine both sprites in group, and use group transform as parent so each of your sprites can have its own transform